# Output variable not being set CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm working on a `CodeIgniter` system with the `Grocery_CRUD` extension. I am trying to integrate a login system with a CRUD application.

Currently I am getting this error when the user logs in, where the CRUD app should be displayed:

**Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: output
Filename: views/members_area.php
Line Number: 13**

This is the line the error is occuring on: `<?php echo $output; ?>`

I realise that `$output` is not being set but I can't see why!! Any ideas?

This is my entire members_area.php file: View

```
<?php
echo '<span class="italic">'.date("l, F d, Y " ,time()).'</span>';
echo '<h3>Welcome: '.$this->session->userdata('username').' '. anchor('logout/signout', 'logout').'</h3>';
?>
<a href='<?php echo site_url('site/dishes_management')?>'>Dishes</a> |
<a href='<?php echo site_url('site/orders_management')?>'>Orders</a> 
<?php echo $output; ?>
```

This is my site.php file: Controller

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->is_logged_in();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    }

    function members_area($output = null){
        $this->load->view('members_area', $output);

    }

    function is_logged_in(){
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true){
            echo 'You need to login to access this page. <a href="../login">Login</a>';
            die();
    }

    function dishes_management()
    {
        try{
            $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
            $crud->set_theme('datatables');
            $crud->set_table('dishes');
            $crud->set_subject('Dish');
            $crud->required_fields('dish_name');
            $crud->columns('dish_name','dish_desc','dish_price', 'dish_cat');
            $output = $crud->render();
            $this->members_area($output);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }

    function orders_management()
    {
            $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
            $crud->set_relation('customerNumber','customers','{contactLastName} {contactFirstName}');
            $crud->display_as('customerNumber','Customer');
            $crud->set_table('orders');
            $crud->set_subject('Order');
            $crud->unset_add();
            $crud->unset_delete();
            $output = $crud->render();
            $this->members_area($output);
    }
}
}
?>
```

By default I would like the `members_area.php` to have output set to display items from the dishes table. This does not seem to be working.

Any help, as always is much appreciated!

Comment: That's really weird. Can you check what the print_r and die show for $output = $crud->render(); . For example: print_r($output); die; If you still having problems, try to start again from scratch from http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/create-crud-codeigniter-tutorial . Can you please tell me what version do you use as well?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried enclosing the output inside an array ?

`$this->load->view('members_area', array('output'=>$output));`

or

```
$output['output'] = $output;
$this->load->view('members_area', $output);
```

You must send it on the views as two dimensional array, codeigniter is trying to find an `output` key from the given data but cannot find it since you have not supplied the proper data for the view to search from.